# DataProvider is not an annotation type

Tags: dataprovider

I am Using TestNG with Selenium WebDriver. I am trying to get the 'data provider' annotation working in my Eclipse IDE. However, after adding overring on the annotation showing error 0

`DataProvider` is not an annotation type

```
 package remoteTesting.dockervalidation;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 public class DataProvider {
 @Test
 public void testcaseData() {}

 @DataProvider (name = "DPS1")
    public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception{
        Object[][] retObjArr= {{"hello","text",1},{"bye","message",1},{"solo","call",453}};
        return(retObjArr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its because your class name is 'DataProvider'. Please change the class name to something else (which will be of more meaning) and try to import DataProvider from testng.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled the TestNG plugin and installed it again and it worked for me.